# Setting up Resque in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

When setting up Resque for the first time in Rails, I'm getting an error.  I'm using Foreman and a Procfile to start my app locally, before eventual deployment to Heroku.  Redis and my PostgreSQL database are already running when I try to start my app.  The error is:

```
$ foreman start
...
23:24:32 resque.1 | rake aborted!
23:24:32 resque.1 | No such file to load -- bootstrap_flash_helper
23:24:32 resque.1 | Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload
23:24:32 resque.1 | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
23:24:32 resque.1 | exited with code 1
...
```

My app does use Bootstrap, but I'm not explicitly requiring it in any classes using Rescue.  My Rakefile and Procfile are:

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=10 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

**Rakefile**

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"

MyCoolApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand this, but wanted to document it in case it helps someone.  I needed the line:

```
task "resque:preload" => :environment
```

in my Rakefile right after the require statements. If anyone knows how this works, please clarify!

Comment: I was getting the error `No such file to load -- actions_controller`. This fixed it on Rails 4

Answer (score 3):

Just use

`bundle exec rake environment resque:work`

this does the same thing with `task "resque:preload" => :environment`.

require current environment when running the task :p